# jQuery DataTables - Strange pagination issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTables containing 2 columns ("Name" & "Description") to be displayed on my web page.

I have the below chunk of code populating the data in the datatable.

```
for (var i=0; i<iData.length; i++) {
    table.fnAddData([iData[i].NAME, iData[i].DESCRIPTION],false);
}
table.fnDraw();
```

The strange part is I have to display 40 Name/description in the table, in which one object contains Name as "British Airways" , on doing previous/next on the table it just loads the objects till it encounters "British Airways" and after that it goes back to the first page in the table.

If I rename this object with any other name/description like "Test","Dummy" etc its works all fine?

Any clue regarding this issue?

```html
<!-- html code snippet-->

    <div class="table_container_diffengine_bank">

                <table id="table_diffenginebank" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

    </div>
```

```html
<!-- JS script for creating the datatable -->

var table = aContext.find('#table_diffenginebank').dataTable({
   "bPaginate": true,
   "bLengthChange": false,
   "bFilter": false,
   "bSort": true,
   "bInfo": false,
   "bAutoFalse": false,
   "bJQueryUI": true,
   "bAutoWidth": false, // Disable the auto width calculation
   "aoColumns": [
    { "sWidth": "30%" }, // position
    { "sWidth": "70%" }  // 1st column width
   ],
   "fnDrawCallback": fnNewDrawCallback("#table_diffenginebank", layoutContext.callAddItemsSelectionDiffBank ),
   "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
    if (!($.urlParam('setName') === null || $.urlParam('setName') == undefined || !$.urlParam('setName'))) {
     if(aData[0]==$.urlParam('setName'))
      nRow.setAttribute('id',"rowid");
    }
   }
  });
```

and then I have a list of values to be populated in this pagination table .

Comment: Can you please provide more code or fiddle link to reproduce issue.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet in my post.

Comment: its the same code as you have mentioned in above post. can you make it on fiddle? also how you are populating 'data' in for loop. is it JSON or array?